# Error afterWriteDispatched(stream_base_commons)

Tags: sentry, sentryreact

[image]

How do you use Sentry?
Sentry Saas (sentry.io)

Which SDK are you using?
@sentry/nextjs

SDK Version
7.84.0

Framework Version
"next": "12.1.5",
Link to Sentry event
https://aitrade.sentry.io/issues/4683896796/?project=4505955396812800&query=&referrer=project-issue-stream

SDK Setup
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs'
import SentryIgnoreList from './src/config/sentry/index'
const SENTRY_DSN = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_DSN
Sentry.init({
dsn: SENTRY_DSN,
ignoreErrors: SentryIgnoreList,
tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
})

the error showed in sentry that crashed my server.
it's from node_modules/@sentry/utils/cjs/instrument/console.js
giving a write EPIPE error

Expected Result
shouldn't give write EPIPE error

Actual Result
EPIPE error and server crashed. only in production after CI/CD is done. then I vist site then it gives this error and crashed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found out problem was our own code in next js. doing infinite render ig sentry crashed before that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).